# dataframe looks the same for different filtration list

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I have several dataframes which I need to filter out some ID.It looks like this:

```
df1
    ID  time    name    value
0   166     2022-05-01_00:02:55     telephone   38.000
1   167     2022-05-01_00:13:04     telephone   21.577
2   161     2022-05-01_00:19:07     telephone   22.406
3   125     2022-05-01_00:34:07     telephone   22.406
4   198     2022-05-01_00:34:08     telephone   34.000
```

```
df2
    ID  time    name    value
0   166     2022-05-02  telephone   38.000
1   167     2022-05-02  telephone   21.577
2   161     2022-05-02  telephone   22.406
3   125     2022-05-02  telephone   22.406
4   198     2022-05-02  telephone   34.000
```

```
df3
    ID  time    name    value
0   166     2022-05-03  telephone   38.000
1   167     2022-05-03  telephone   21.577
2   161     2022-05-03  telephone   22.406
3   125     2022-05-03  telephone   22.406
4   198     2022-05-03  telephone   34.000
```

but they are much bigger.

I have also three filtration list, lets say it looks like this:

```
filtration_1 = [166,167]
filtration_2 = [161,125]
filtration_3 = [125,198]
```

And what I am trying to do is to filter out every dataframe separetly and then concat them together like this:

```
list1 = open(f"{filtration_1}", "r")
list2 = open(f"{filtration_2}", "r")
list3 = open(f"{filtration_3}", "r")

lines1 = []
for line1 in list1:
    lines1.append(line1.strip())

lines2 = []
for line2 in list2:
    lines2.append(line2.strip())

lines3 = []
for line3 in list3:
    lines3.append(line3.strip())

df1 = pd.read_csv(data1, sep ="\t", names=["ID","time","name","value"])
df2 = pd.read_csv(data2, sep ="\t", names=["ID","time","name","value"])
df3 = pd.read_csv(data3, sep ="\t", names=["ID","time","name","value"])

new_df1 = df1[~df1.ID.isin(lines1)]
new_df2 = df2[~df2.ID.isin(lines2)]
new_df3 = df3[~df3.ID.isin(lines3)]

frames = [new_df1, new_df2, new_df3]
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

The problem is - my output looks like concat df1, df2, df3, not new_df1,new_df2,new_df3. So my filtration list isn't working for some reason and I don't know why. Would be greatful for letting me now what am I doing wrong.

Comment: why is processing lists `filtration_1, filtration_2, filtration_3` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply pass lists:

```
new_df1 = df1[~df1.ID.isin(filtration_1)]
new_df2 = df2[~df2.ID.isin(filtration_2)]
new_df3 = df3[~df3.ID.isin(filtration_3)]

frames = [new_df1, new_df2, new_df3]
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

Reason why solution not working is in `lines1, lines2, lines3` is not what expected - lists `filtration_1,filtration_2, filtration_3`.